# Where to ask questions about programming languages themselves?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Note that this question is much more specific than ["Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598), and the accepted answer there does not answer my question clearly (but it seems to suggest StackOverflow as the answer).

Here are a few examples of questions about programming languages themselves, not about their application or particular implementation:

- [In Scheme, what is formally a program's state?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193416)
- [How can a statically typed language support duck typing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/252984)
- [Why doesn't Java have optimization for tail-recursion at all?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/272061)
- [What is the name of λx.λf.fx (like reverse `apply`) in lambda calculus? Does the corresponding function have a standard name in programming?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/198575)

The question I have in mind for asking would be: "Scheme's facilities for building expressions with interpolation (quasiquoting) seem incomplete, what are the alternatives?".

For asking questions about programming languages, the only alternatives among the Stack Exchange sites that I can currently (2017) think of are:

- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic),
- [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), and
- [Comput(er/ing) Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

I believe that for quite some time already Stack Overflow is reserved for practical issues.  Once I posted there a [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193416) about Scheme, and it got migrated to Programmers/SoftwareEngineering.

I used to ask questions about programming languages on Programmers.SE, but that site was converted into Software Engineering <s>and its scope changed</s>.  Now it is reserved for questions about

- software development methods and practices
- requirements, architecture, and design
- quality assurance and testing
- configuration management, build, release, and deployment

Programming language syntax and semantics do not fit into any of these categories.

There is left the site about Computing Science, which seems to be a good fit as questions about

- programming language semantics, formal methods

are allowed, but I noticed that they do not even have tags for individual programming languages.

I am a bit lost.

Comment: What type of question? Can you [edit] your question to include an example of a question you'd like to ask?

Comment: Software Engineering didn't change it's scope when it changed it's name, it just changed the name *without changing the scope at all* because it's scope was so frequently misunderstood by people who thought it was for something that it wasn't.  The site has had the same scope since before you joined the site (its scope was only ever different for a few months when it was in private beta).

Comment: @ale, just questions about programming languages themselves, which are not about solving particular problems.  Like [this one](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193416).

Comment: @Servy, thanks for the clarification, then i must have been wrong. Does this mean that questions about programming languages themselves were never appropriate for that site?

Comment: @Alexey Not necessarily.  it would depend on what type of question you have.   Since you still haven't provided more information about the type of questions you're interested in, with respect to programming languages, we couldn't say.

Comment: @Servy, i provided examples.

Comment: I believe Schemers on SO wouldn't downvote such question, especially if it were presented with some code and specifics of what you think is missing (so it doesn't look like unsubstantiated claim).

Comment: @WillNess, my question is about the right site to ask my other question. Note that [my previous question about Scheme](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193416) got migrated from SO to Programmers, which is now renamed to Software Engineering, but my questions have not much to do with software engineering.

Comment: This is a bit like as if i had a question about the use of the past perfect tense, and only had a choice between a site about poetry and a site about journalism.

Comment: I don't understand much in that kind of stuff, but your quasiquotation (why is it "interpolation"?) question seems specific enough for SO.

Comment: @WillNess, "interpolation" -- like in "string interpolation".  I am afraid that while i was trying to figure out where to ask, i found a rather satisfactory solution myself :).

Comment: you can post  question and answer at the same time, if you feel like sharing.

Comment: @Mureinik, i do not think so. My question is clearly much more specific, and the accepted answer to the question you linked to does not really answer my question. It seems to suggest, however (among everything else), that questions about real-life programming languages should be asked on SO.  However, i had one such [question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/193416) migrated from SO to Software Engineering.